# Is there a log to see what rspec is actually doing when test are being run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, integration-testing

So I'm trying to write some tests for my API

I have this url
/v1/users?api_key=1:--XsF99m7wcvFFzTt-Js

which if I go to it in the browser works fine and a bit of JSON is returned.

However, in my test is

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "GET /users/index" do

  it 'returns a 200' do
    get "/v1/users?api_key=1:--XsF99m7wcvFFzTt-Js"
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
 end
```

and when I run the RSpec it give me this error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template v1/users/index, api_v1/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

Which i don't understand why as if i paste the url into the browser it works fine.

So firstly is there anything wrong with that respec test?
Also in terms of debugging how are you meant to debug? As I can't see any log file like you would if you were doing it through the browser and would see development.log filling up

Comment: Is this a controller spec or a request spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, you're trying to test a JSON response for an API. However, it looks like you're requesting the HTML format in your GET request.

Is your view for `users/index` a JSON view? If so, that's the source of your error and specifying `format: :json` in your `GET` request should fix the issue. You can also specify json type for all your actions using

```
before do
   request.accept = "application/json"
end
```

At the start of your describe action.

Per your original question, RSpec tests are logged in `log/test.log`.

Comment: When I'm running my tests nothing is being logged in my log folder, test.log doesn't even exists. Is there anything specifically you have to do to enable logging?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `render_views` to your describe block.
2. You can tail or view your `test.log` that lives in the `/log/` folder.

Comment: When i have put render_views in the describe block i've got this error "undefined local variable or method `render_views' "